# HybridAuth Facebook Invalid Scope: Array (Please check lower letter case or delimiter)

Tags: facebook, hybridauth

Facebook started returning this error a few days ago:

***"Invalid Scope: Array (Please check lower letter case or delimiter)"***

I haven't made a changes to the login functionality, or facebook app setting in a while. Any idea what's wrong with this scope, or what changed?

```
$config = [
        'callback' => HttpClient\Util::getCurrentUrl(),
        'providers' => [
            PROVIDER => [
                "enabled" => true,
                "keys"    => [
                "id" => "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn",
                "secret" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ],
                "scope"   => ['public_profile', 'email']
            ],         
        ],
    ];
```

The uri for the facebook error page is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxxxxxxx.com%2Ffacebook-login.php&scope[0]=public_profile&scope[1]=email&state=HA-nnnnxnnnnxnnnnxnnnnxnnnnxnnnnxnnnx
```

You can try my Facebook login here:
https://trailsnh.com/dashboard.php

Comment: I changed my scope to this, and that seemed to fix it: 
"scope"   => 'email,public_profile'

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you fixed it by changing it to comma-separated string, and that's great. The docs about this are on the [Facebook Developer site](http://scope.%20A%20comma%20or%20space%20separated%20list%20of%20Permissions%20to%20request%20from%20the%20person%20using%20your%20app.). There, they say:

> scope. A comma or space separated list of Permissions to request from the person using your app.

Personally, I would change it space-separated since that's what's [defined in the OAuth specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3):

> The value of the scope parameter is expressed as a list of space-delimited, case-sensitive strings.

If it changes again at Facebook, I would expect it to remain compliant with the spec. So, if you change it to anything, I think that's the more bulletproof option.